# React: Converting DateTime from Database within my Axios Call

Tags: reactjs, knex.js, bookshelf.js, luxon, react-calendar

I'm trying to figure out how to convert my database's dates with LUXON within the axios call, is this possible or should I change it within the database data itself?

Here's my code below:

```
 const onClickDay = (date) => {
        // setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
        // setDay(date.getDate());
        // setyear(date.getFullYear());
    
        getAllData().then((res) => {
          setSave(res[1]);
          setExpense(res[2]);
    
          const getSaveDates = save.map((item) => {
            const d = item.date;
            const saveConverted = DateTime.fromISO(d).toLocaleString();
          });
        });
        console.log(save);
      };
```

I have it later converted when it's rendered however, I'm also using [react-calendar](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) as a component and trying to get the date to be converted beforehand for my onClick handler to render the dates on it's respected day.

As of right now the data is in ISO-8601 date format, i.e 2020-12-21T20:06:52+0000

Maybe you guys have some more experience with it? please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

There are four basic forms for the Date() constructor:

1. No parameters
2. Time value or timestamp number
3. Timestamp string
4. Individual date and time component values

so I think you can solve your problem using this code:

```js
const getSaveDates = save.map((item) => {
    const d = new Date(item.date)
    const saveConverted = d.toLocaleString();
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, After working around it, I ended up solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some lost souls, I solved a part of my issue with...

```
     const onClickDay = (date) => {
    // setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    // setDay(date.getDate());
    // setyear(date.getFullYear());
    getAllData().then((res) => {
      setSave(res[1]);
      setExpense(res[2]);
    });
    const getSaveDates = save.map((item) => {
      const d = item.date;
      const saveConverted = DateTime.fromISO(d).toLocaleString();
      return { ...item, date: saveConverted };
    });
    const getExpenseDate = expense.map((item) => {
      const d = item.date;
      const expenseConverted = DateTime.fromISO(d).toLocaleString();
      return { ...item, date: expenseConverted };
    });
    setData([getExpenseDate, getSaveDates]);
  };
  console.log(data);
```